# Why was the Past Perfect put in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Saw it in a song (the lyrics) and was wondering why.

"Oh, Those funny shows I cried watching once, and all the music that **had changed** my life. None of them speak to me anymore"

Don't we use the Past Perfect to talk about an event in the past that happened before another event?

Comment: It's not ideal. It probably just fits the rhythm better (which is why lyrics are usually off-topic on ELU).

Comment: Is the Past Perfect always used when you want to talk about an event that happened before another event in the past? Some of my teachers told me that you use it to go further back in the past than you already are. Something like "He got up, went to the kitchen, looked in the refrigerator, it was almost empty. He HAD forgotten to go shopping

Comment: Here is your order: Last year (perhaps) I cried watching shows, but way before that all the music had already changed my life. When you compare *cried* and *had changed*, you show the reader knows which came first.

Comment: No. Often, where there is an adverbial say quite adequately showing sequence of events, the past perfect is seen as unnecessary. 'I had twisted my ankle before the crash took place' in most contexts probably sounds slightly less natural than  'I twisted my ankle before the crash took place'. And of course there's no plu-pluperfect etc for 'A before B before C'.